# Plot a surface in 3D, using the same colormap as 2d contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, contourf, matplotlib-3d

I used a 2d Plot with contourf mapping:

```
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22, 20), dpi=400)
   pc = plt.contourf(ygrid, zgrid, data[1])
   colorbar = plt.colorbar(pc)
   colorbar.set_label('u-Speed', fontsize=45)
   colorbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=30)
   txt = "t = {t:.1f}"
   plt.title(txt.format(t = time[1]),fontsize=45,pad=35)
   plt.tick_params(direction="in", which="both", labelsize=30)
   # plt.xlim(-100, 100)
   # plt.ylim(-100, 100)
   plt.axis('image')
   plt.xlabel("Y", fontsize=30)
   plt.ylabel("Z", fontsize=30)
```

[The result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhyn4.jpg)

what I am actually trying is to represent my data in a 3D plot with the same colormap: the nearest I got is a representation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(22, 20), dpi=400)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
xx = np.zeros_like(ygrid)
yy, zz = ygrid, zgrid

cmap = pc.get_cmap()
norm = pc.norm(data[1])
rgb_values = cmap(norm)
rgba_values = cmap(norm, alpha=1.0)


ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, facecolors=rgba_values, shade=False)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjjBT.jpg)

Since my grid points are not really much, it is not really nice representation. How could I use the colormaping of the 2D plot instead.